# NavigationLink stays highlighted when List is not only child

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have the following view with a `NavigationView` and a `List`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var sheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Lorem Ipsum")
                List {
                    ForEach(1...30, id: \.self) { i in
                        NavigationLink(String(i), destination: EmptyView())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the fact that there is a `Text` view on top of the `List`, it's making the `NavigationLink` to stay highlighted when clicked and coming back to the main view.

[image]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it can be fixed by setting a higher `.zIndex()` on all the other sibilings, like this.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var sheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Lorem Ipsum")
                    .zIndex(1)
                List {
                    ForEach(1...30, id: \.self) { i in
                        NavigationLink(String(i), destination: EmptyView())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```